# Android String Escape?

Tags: android, escaping

How To Escape String Like Below.
I Use Below Code But Say

"The method **unescape**(String) is undefined for the type printpreview"

String s = **unescape**(stringFromDatabase)

I saw this method from this link:

[New Line character \n not displaying properly in textView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586763/new-line-character-n-not-displaying-properly-in-textview-android)

I want to **"Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5"** String to below but not work

Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Line 4

Line 5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should define it yourself ;-).

a suggestion from the thread you were refering to was

```
private String unescape(String description) {
   return description.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\\n");
```

}

But off course it depends what you are trying to do whether this will work.