# Newline and tab are not displaying properly

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I'm getting some data from an SQLite database. The data consists of text and some tabs (\t) and newline (\n) elements. When I print the string from a file, everything is shown correctly, but if I get my string from the database, the newline and tabs are shown in text.

For example:

```
This is my first row\tText afterTab\nThis is my second row\tText after second tab
```

Here is my sourcecode:

java:

```
textfieldAntwort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAntwort);
textfieldAntwort.setText(frageundantwort.getAntwort());
```

xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAntwort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewFrage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ima_frage"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_answer" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Line character \n not displaying properly in textView Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586763/new-line-character-n-not-displaying-properly-in-textview-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unescape your string

```
String s = unescape(stringFromDatabase)
```

before you place it in your TextView.

```
private String unescape(String description) {
   return description.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\\n").replaceAll("\\\\t", "\\\t");
}
```

Source: [New Line character \n not displaying properly in textView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586763/new-line-character-n-not-displaying-properly-in-textview-android)

Comment: This method is undefined...Is there an alternative?

Comment: Terribly sorry, the function is defined on the linked question. I'll update my answer.