# New line character \n not working in arabic text in textview of android

Tags: java, android

I have Arabic text inside a `TextView`.

I have added `\n` character to the String but it's not producing expected results.

Below is the String:

> ك بتوفير مزيد من الأمان والراحة لكلا الطرفين المؤجر و المستأجر، بناءً
> على احتياجاتهم، وعليه أنشأت الشركة تطبيقًا يُطلق عليه تطبيق إن ، وهو
> ما جعل تحصيل
>
> تسعى شركة أبيليتيز لإدارة العقارات (ذ. م. م) جاهدةً لتطوير وتحسين هذا
> الجانب من إدارة العقارات

I want last line of Arabic text on  a new line.

Comment: Try the following, instead of \n use \r\n.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586763/new-line-character-n-not-displaying-properly-in-textview-android

Answer (score 3):

Write `n\` instead of `\n`. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n` or whatever. As is it is different in Andorid .

Please Refer This : [New Line character \n not displaying properly in textView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586763/new-line-character-n-not-displaying-properly-in-textview-android?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can define it in strings.xml file like this :

`<string name="arabic_text">ك بتوفير مزيد من الأمان والراحة لكلا الطرفين المؤجر و المستأجر، بناءً على احتياجاتهم، وعليه أنشأت الشركة تطبيقًا يُطلق عليه تطبيق إن ، وهو ما جعل تحصيل \n تسعى شركة أبيليتيز لإدارة العقارات (ذ. م. م) جاهدةً لتطوير وتحسين هذا الجانب من إدارة العقارات</string>`

`Then use it in textview :
android:text="@string/arabic_text"`

Answer (score 0):

Open the "string.xml (ar)" and put \n and there you go.
Do not put it in the editor

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
"String One" + "\n" + "String Two";
```